# Flipclock js. Add minutes after condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

How does one extend the duration of the countdown timer by adding 2 minutes(eg) to the existing timer if a condition is met?

Current Code :

```
    var clock = $('#countdownClock').FlipClock(minutes * 60, {
        clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
        autoStart: false,
        countdown: true,
        showSeconds: true,
        callbacks: {
            interval: function () {
                var time = clock.getTime().time;
                var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
                var seconds = time - minutes * 60;
                var total = minutes + ":" + seconds
                console.log(minutes + ":" + seconds);

                if (minutes < 2) {
                    if (counter == 0) {
                        counter++;
            }
        }
    })
    clock.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by stopping the timer, adding time and starting again. effectively doing a reset? i think?

```
$('.reset').click(function(){
                        var time = clock.getTime().time;
                        clock.stop();
                        clock.setTime(time+120);
                        clock.start();
});
```

Comment: Yes, you would probably need to extend the original library with a method to add seconds, since it doesn't seem to expose it. Resetting the timer is the way to go, without modifying the sources. However, keep in mind, that the result time would not be accurate in that case and there will be a sub-second deviation. Probably not important for most cases though.

Comment: yeah the timer in my project doesn't need to be so accurate to the very millisecond etc, i'm not that confident in my abilities to extend the original library to add seconds so i think i will just have to use this method since its easier to understand/code.